# How to obtain Enum value from stringified XML?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, vb.net

I have a method that gets as parameter a **stringified**  XML and returns an object with specific fields of the string as its properties.The fields are mapped with class fields.

So far i can get the result (processedObj) with two properties(Id,Title) but not  the Enum property . How can i make it recognizable and obtain its current value ?

Main class

```
email.Content = '<EmailClass><ID>210</ID><Title>Urgent</Title><Date>2020-06-01</Date> 
              <Action>Delete</Action></EmailClass>'

Dim processedObj = XmlProcessor.ObjectfromStrXml(Of EmailClass)(email.Content)
```

EmailClass class

```
<Serializable()>
<XmlRoot("EmailClass")>
Public Class EmailClass

    Public ID As String
    Public Title As String
 
    Public Enum Action
        Send
        Delete
    End Enum

End Class
```

XmlProcessor class

```
public static T ObjectfromStrXml<T>(string p_StrXML){
            T result;
            using (MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(p_StrXML)))
            using (StreamReader stReader = new StreamReader(mStream , Encoding.UTF8))
            using (XmlReader reader = new XmlTextReader(stReader))
            {
                XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
                result = (T)(serializer.Deserialize(reader));
                streamReader.Close();
                memoryStream.Close();
                reader.Close();
            }

            return result;
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what isn't working?  You shouldn't need to do the answer below, it's supposed to just work.  The XmlSerializer is supposed to know how to process enums, and you should only need to intervene when the XML text is different from the enum item names.

Comment: Just to elaborate: You already have the enum, you should just need a public property of that enum type, e.g. `Public Property Action As Action` (you might need to rename the enum type to avoid confusing the compile).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try code below  :

```
Public Class EmailClass

    Public ID As String
    Public Title As String
    Private PAction As EAction

    Public Property Action As String
        Get
            Return PAction.ToString()
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            PAction = [Enum].Parse(GetType(EAction), value)
        End Set
    End Property


    Public Enum EAction
        Send
        Delete
    End Enum

End Class
```

Comment: See my comments on the question.  I think this is over-complicated.

Comment: You need to read the string enumeration from xml file and parse of the enum object.  It is not over complicated.

Comment: The XML serialization machinery should already do this for you for an enum type.  Also see the docs for XmlEnumAttribute, which appears to only be needed if the XML strings are different from the enum member names.  Even in the alternative where the attribute is needed for same-name strings, I'd still prefer that approach to having a separate string and enum property.

Comment: It is an element not an attribute.

Comment: I'm talking about the XML side, where XmlEnumAttribute is an attribute that can be applied to members of an enum and which the XML serialization/deserialization machinery will use to figure out how to serialize/deserialize an enum.